# Bootstrap icons not appear in the react js project

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have created a react project using following command:

```
npx create-react-app project
```

I have installed bootstrap 4.3.1 using npm command and I have also imported bootstrap into the index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

But for some reason it is not displaying icons.

```
export class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-dark mb-5">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="navbar-header">
                            <a className="navbar-brand text-white text-lg brand-text" to="/">
                                MovieSeriesInfo</a>
                        </div>
                        <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto text-light d-inline-block">
                            <li className="nav-item d-inline-block mr-4">
                                <i className="fab fa-imdb fa-5x" id="imdb-logo" />
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item d-inline-block mr-4">
                                <i className="fab fa-react fa-5x" id="react-logo" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to install `font-awesome` and import the same,

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

import in `index.js` file

```
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

For more on how to use `font-awesome` icons see [this](https://fontawesome.com/icons).

Comment: Have you added font awesome?

Comment: How to add font awesome?

Comment: I guess the question is asking about the `bootstrap` icons. Could you provide any reason to use the `front-awsome` instead of `bootstrap`? Although I saw there is another answer down below saying bootstrap one may not work, I want to hear your idea.

Comment: I agree with @JasonLiu

Comment: @JasonLiu Though the user has added "Bootstrap icons" words in the question title, his syntax "<i className="fab fa-imdb fa-5x" id="imdb-logo" />" seems to be from the "Font-awesome" only.

Comment: @ravibagul91 Thanks for pointing that out. Your answer makes a lot of sense.

Comment: why does font-awesome never mention "font-awesome" package and always in their documentation you can see "@fortawesome/..." . what is font-awesome package and where you can find reference to it in official font-awesome website?

Answer (score 66):

> **First, you should install "bootstrap-icons" npm package**:

```
npm install bootstrap-icons
```

> **Then, import "bootstrap-icons.css" in your index.js file**:

```
import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";
```

Comment: This answer applies to bootstrap v5x

Comment: @AndresZapata
Negative, it's not even depends on bootstrap to use it. it works even without adding bootstrap to the project, and whether bootstrap V4 or V5

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has an accepted answer, but it's for others who did the same mistake as I did. Add this `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">` tag in `index.html`, it has the web fonts cdn link. It's given in bootstrap's [usage](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#usage) to add this link for icon fonts. Don' just install and the `<i>` tag. I found it [here](http://johna.compoutpost.com/blog/1189/how-to-use-the-new-bootstrap-icons-v1-2-web-font/)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know `Bootstrap 4.*` doesn't support `Glyphicon` natively, so you should use an alternative, or downgrade to `bootstrap 3.*` which is not recommended. `Fontawesome.com` is an option.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but i had the same issue, i had already npm installed and done the  in my index.html but the icon still wasn't showing up untill i add this @import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css"); in my index.css